# Node.js HTTPS server verification failed

Tags: node.js, azure, https

I create a Node.js app with HTTPS protocol. I followed a tutorial from nodejitsu https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/

But when I sent a request to the server, I git the following error:

```
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

When I opened from Chrome, I can only access the page after pressing advanced and proceed to the page.

This is what I filled when generating the certificate:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:ID
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:East Java
Locality Name (eg, city) []:[my city name]
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:[some string]
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:[some string]
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:[IP address of the server (Azure server) without port and 'https://']
Email Address []:[my personal yahoo email]
Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:[empty]
An optional company name []:[empty]
```

The app is hosted on Azure server.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is the certificate valid? Is it by any chance a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Self-Signed certificate which is causing verification failure. You need to get a signed certificate to remove the validation error.